# Resample TimedeltaIndex and normalize to frequency

Tags: pandas

For example, I have got this `Series` :

```
17:50:51.050929    5601
17:52:15.429169    5601
17:52:19.538702    5601
17:53:44.776350    5601
17:53:51.870372    5598
17:55:33.952417    5600
17:56:48.736539    5596
17:57:01.205767    5593
17:57:26.066097    5593
17:57:30.644398    5591
```

I want to resample it but I want that the index start to a rounded frequency. 
So in the case above, I want the first index `17:51:00` if I resample on `Min` frequency.

However Pandas implements it like that :

```py
a.resample('1T', 'mean')

Out[125]: 
17:50:51.050929    5601.000000
17:51:51.050929    5601.000000
17:52:51.050929    5601.000000
17:53:51.050929    5598.000000
17:54:51.050929    5600.000000
17:55:51.050929    5596.000000
17:56:51.050929    5592.333333
17:57:51.050929            NaN
```

How can I have a `TimedeltaIndex` starting from a rounded index ? Such as `Timestamp` resampling

Comment: So are you asking how to remove the microseconds from your timestamp?

Comment: I want to ceil the timedelta

Comment: Please edit your question and show the desired output

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do it is to normalise the index before resampling (using either `floor`, `ceil`, or `round`):

```
a.index = a.index.floor(freq='1T')
a = a.resample('1T').mean()
```